# Normalized Wasserstein distance

Tags: python, scipy, wasserstein

The [wasserstein_distance](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance.html) will be smaller the longer `u_values` and `v_values` are.

```
from scipy.stats import wasserstein_distance

def wassersteindist(n):    
    a = np.random.randn(n)
    b = np.random.randn(n)
    w = wasserstein_distance(a,b)
    return w
     
np.mean([wassersteindist(100) for r in range(1000)])
0.1786
np.mean([wassersteindist(1000) for r in range(1000)])
0.0579
np.mean([wassersteindist(10000) for r in range(1000)])
0.0180
```

Is there a way to calculate a normalized wasserstein distance with scipy?

EDIT:
Let's say I 'm interested in comparing the distances from different individuals that happened to have a different amount of time points in their time series.

```
id1_a = np.random.randn(100)
id1_b = np.random.randn(100)

id2_a = np.random.randn(1000)
id2_b = np.random.randn(1000)

id1_dist = wasserstein_distance(id1_a, id1_b)
0.3539204677483332

id2_dist = wasserstein_distance(id2_a, id2_b)
0.0685546301855615
```

`id1_dist` is larger than `id2_dist` only because the vectors for `id1` are shorter than for `id2`.

EDIT2:

With correlations I don't have the problem that they are consistently lower/higher for longer time series:

```
def corrr(n):    
    a = np.random.randn(n)
    b = np.random.randn(n)
    c = np.corrcoef(a,b)[0][1]
    return c

np.mean([corrr(100) for r in range(1000)])
0.0004

np.mean([corrr(1000) for r in range(1000)])
0.0012

np.mean([corrr(100) for r in range(1000)])
-0.0001

np.mean([corrr(1000) for r in range(1000)])
-0.0008
```

Comment: Why would you want to normalize it?  And normalize it relative to what?

Comment: @jbowman, I have edited my question with more information. Essentially, I would like to compare distances that were computed using a different amount of time points

Comment: The problem with this version of your previous question is that it lacks a statement of *purpose* and does not tell us much, if anything, about the *probability model* you are using to understand your data.  That information will help us (or anyone else) answer both questions with suitable recommendations.

Comment: @whuber, I'm sorry for the lack of clarity with my questions. 
I have collected physiological data from several individuals (id) and grouped them according to a grouping factor (4 groups). Each id has two time series (x and y) that are the same length. However, one id could have 700 data points in x and y, whereas another could have 1400 datapoints.
I could correlate the two signals for each id and compare the average correlation values among the groups, but I was simply looking for complementary measures of similarity.

Comment: @whuber, does my comment above help in any way? I'm not sure myself what the probability model could be. I was just looking for alternative measures of relationship between signals beyond correlations.

Comment: However, the wasserstein distance is sensitive to the amount of data points I use in its computation. With the Euclidean distance, the solution to use the square root of n after computing the distance does seem to normalize distances of different lengths, but that won't work with wasserstein distance...

Comment: It helps a little, but I am left wondering what you are trying to achieve.  *Why* -- to what end -- are you contemplating these comparisons?

Comment: For each subject I recorded ECG time series at two electrodes placed in different locations. I split my sample into 3 treatment groups + 1 placebo group. I expect subjects in group A to show a higher correlation between the two measured ECGs relative to the other groups. However, even in group A, the length of the ECG time series varies among subjects. So wasserstein distances will be biased for those subjects with longer ECGs relative to the ones with shorter ECGs. Thus I need a way to normalize the distances so I'm able to compare/average distances without bias.

Comment: @whuber, but I'm wondering now if that will be possible. If I'm reading passerby51's answer accurately, it seems that a normalized wasserstein distance that is invariable to size doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that this distance is going down in your case is a good thing. In general, for two samples with empirical distributions $\mathbb P_n$ and $\mathbb Q_m$, we have have
$$
W(\mathbb P_n, \mathbb Q_m) \to W(\mathbb P, \mathbb Q)
$$
as $m, n \to \infty$. Here, $\mathbb P$ and $\mathbb Q$ are the population versions of the two distributions. In your simulations, the two samples are are coming from the same population $\mathbb P = \mathbb Q = N(0,1)$, hence $W(\mathbb P, \mathbb Q) = 0$. As $n,m \to \infty$, you should expect $W(\mathbb P_n, \mathbb Q_m)$ to approach zero.

For you time series, if they are coming from two different populations, $W(\mathbb P, \mathbb Q)$ will be nonzero, so you will converge to something nonzero for large samples.

In other words, you want $W(\mathbb P_n, \mathbb Q_m)$ to vary with $m$ and $n$ to get more accurate for larger samples. In general (in the 1-D case),
$$\mathbb E[ W(\mathbb P_n, \mathbb Q_m) ] = W(\mathbb P,\mathbb Q) + O\Bigr(\frac1{\sqrt{n \wedge m}}\Bigl).$$
Normalizing $W(\mathbb P_n, \mathbb Q_m)$ to be invariant to the sample size does not make much sense, especially when $\mathbb P = \mathbb Q$.

---

In case you are curious where that rate comes from, first note that by triangle inequality
$$W(\mathbb P_n, \mathbb Q_m) \le W(\mathbb P_n, \mathbb P) + W(\mathbb P, \mathbb Q) + W(\mathbb Q, \mathbb Q_m).$$
Then, use a result like that of [Fournier and Guillin](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.2128) on the first and third terms.

---

EDIT1: The same problem is there with the absolute value of Pearson correlation coefficient:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1337)

def corrr(n):    
    a = np.random.randn(n)
    b = np.random.randn(n)
    c = np.corrcoef(a,b)[0][1]
    return c

for n in [10, 100, 1000, 10000]:
    print(np.mean([abs(corrr(n)) for r in range(1000)]))
```

which produces the following output:

```
0.2709428042954994
0.07715058968038786
0.023744887030041146
0.008094465791386103
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. So if I understood your answer, comparing wasserstein distances that were computed with vectors of different lengths do not make sense?

Comment: That is not quite what I said. Looking at your comments on the original post,  you seem to be OK with computing correlations when the two times series have different sizes (?) This is very much similar. If you are OK with that, you can be OK with this too. (Sample correlation is an estimate of the population correlation. Sample Wasserstein is an estimate of the population Wasserstein.)

Comment: Thanks @passerby51. But with correlations I'm not having the problem that individuals with longer time series have consistently lower/higher correlation values than those with shorter time series (see Edit2). But with wasserstein distance there will be a bias. In the extreme case that all subjects in group B have longer time series than subjects in group A, I will for sure find a difference between the two groups just due to the fact that the time series for subjects in group B is longer... This won't happen with correlations.

Comment: @HappyPy, You have the same problem with correlation, but since correlation is signed you are not seeing it (Wasserstein is always nonnegative). Try calculating the absolute value of the correlation. See the updated code in my edited response. On a side note, there is always a way to normalize a statistic in statistics, via figuring out its null distribution. As long as you have an idea what your null is, there is a way.

Comment: thanks for the edit, I had never thought of correlations in that way. Then is it possible to construct the null distribution based on my actual data? Should I post another question about this?

Comment: @HappyPy No problem. You can try posting another question, but answering that would require more information. You have to have some idea of what the null is. Alternatively, have a look at this R package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/energy/index.html If I recall correctly, do some form of bootstrap to calculate the null distribution of the distance correlation which is a close cousin of Wasserstein. Also, you can try searching for bootstrapping MMD (another relative of these guys).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a metric that can be used to estimate the distance between two sets of data that is not sensitive to the size of each sample or to the scale of the data, you might want to consider the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic, which is implemented in scipy [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html).